# Integrate Struts with Spring

Tags: spring, integration, struts-1

I saw a bunch of articles about how to integrate Struts 1.3.x with Spring 3.0.x and they all reference deprecated classes.

What is the right and up-to-date approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deprecated classes *are* the approach if you must implement Struts 1.3 and Spring 3.0.

Struts 1 is quite old and there's little reason for newer Spring versions to continue supporting it.

In other words, if you *continue* to use old Struts, *and* old Spring, everything is fine.

If you want to keep versioning Spring, however, you'll run into issues, because the deprecated classes/methods may or may not exist in future revisions.

Ideally you'd migrate to Struts 2 or Spring MVC, but obviously that isn't always possible.